# Spring PostMethod returns the date from UTC

Tags: java, rest, datetime, timezone, date-format

I have a simple app with rest сontroller.The app runs in Docker.

```
@RestController
@Slf4j
public class TimeTestController {
    @PostMapping("/time-test")
    public @ResponseBody TimeTest timeTest (@RequestBody TimeTest timeTest) {
        log.info("request {}",  timeTest);
        TimeTest time = new TimeTest();
        time.setDate(timeTest.getDate());
        return time;
    }
}
```

And simple class like this

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class TimeTest {
    private String id;
    private Date date;
}
```

I pass the date with the time zone to the controller `2020-12-07T19:54:25.860+0100`. However, in the method, the date is printed with timeZone UTC `2020-12-07T18:54:25.860+0000`. And it also returns with timeZone UTC, but I need to return with the same zone as it came. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Java's `Date` a) doesn't support timezone & b) shouldn't be used if you are on Java 8+. I'd suggest using `OffsetDateTime` here instead.

Assuming you are using Jackson w/ Spring Boot, in addition to the `web` starter make sure to include `jackson-datatype-jsr310` as a dependency. When Boot detects it on the classpath, it will automatically configure Jackson's `JavaTimeModule`, which supports the new Java8 Date/Time APIs.

Good luck!

Comment: Or OffsetDateTime, given that there's no actual time zone indicated.

Comment: @Jon Skeet Do I need to write my own Converter? I get an error "Cannot deserialize value of type java.time.OffsetDateTime from String "2019-12-02T12:54:25.860+0100""

Comment: @Violetta: I don't know anything about the technology you're using to do the conversion. All I know is that the logical type for a value of "2019-12-02T12:54:25.860+0100" is OffsetDateTime.

Comment: Hadn't had my coffee yet; changed ZonedDateTime to OffsetDateTime.

Comment: @Jamie Bisotti I'm using Spring boot. As far as I understand, libraries are already included in the web starter. I changed the input to +01: 00. But I still get UTC 2019-12-02T11:54:25.860Z

Comment: Check to see if the ` jackson-datatype-jsr310` dependency is present. I think it needs to be added separately. If Boot detects it on the classpath, it will automatically configure it.

Answer (score 2):

It seems your JVM's time zone is UTC. The problem with implementations based on `java.util.Date` is that in most cases, they display the date-time in the JVM's time zone. I recommend you use the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html). Since your date-time string, `2020-12-07T19:54:25.860+0100` has zone offset information, the most appropriate class to use is `OffsetDateTime`.

```
@RestController
@Slf4j
public class TimeTestController {
    @PostMapping("/time-test")
    public @ResponseBody TimeTest timeTest (@RequestBody TimeTest timeTest) {
        log.info("request {}",  timeTest);
        TimeTest time = new TimeTest();
        time.setOdt(timeTest.getDate());// Change timeTest.getDate() to return OffsetDateTime
        return time;
    }
}
```

and then in the class, `TimeTest`

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class TimeTest {
    private String id;
    private OffsetDateTime odt;
}
```

Learn more about the modern date-time API at **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Comment: Do I need to write my own Converter? I get an error "Cannot deserialize value of type `java.time.OffsetDateTime` from String "2019-12-02T12:54:25.860+0100""

Comment: @Violetta Some date-time libraries such as *java.time* expect the optional parts of string inputs. So include the COLON character between the hours and minutes of your ISO 8601 string: `"2019-12-02T12:54:25.860+01:00"`. The `OffsetDateTime` class can then parse the input string by default with no need to specify a formatting pattern.

Comment: Thanks, @BasilBourque for the support. I am surprised why I didn't get notification of OP's comment while I got notification of your comment as expected.